# .ipa file fom build.phonegap.com is not working in iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, phonegap-build

I am working on phonegap to build an application for both android and iPhone. This is the first application I am building for phonegap but I am facing some severe issues. **Firstly I am explaining what I am doing in this application**

I have created a www folder which consist of two html file(index.html,dashboard.html) and some css and js(there is a cordova.js which is in [Phonegap 2.9.0](http://phonegap.com/install/)) files.

And I have created a config.xml file.

And after that I have made a zip file and paste it in the upload section in https://build.phonegap.com

Here is my config.xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<cordova>
<!--
access elements control the Android whitelist.
Domains are assumed blocked unless set otherwise
 -->

<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
<!-- <access origin="https://example.com" /> allow any secure requests to example.com -->
<!-- <access origin="https://example.com" subdomains="true" /> such as above, but including subdomains, such as www -->
<access origin="http://google.com" subdomains="true" />


<access origin=".*"/>

<!-- <content src="http://mysite.com/myapp.html" /> for external pages -->
<!-- <content src="index.html" />-->

<log level="DEBUG"/>
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.9.0" />
<preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="true" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<plugins>
<plugin name="App" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
<plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
<plugin name="Device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
<plugin name="Accelerometer" value="org.apache.cordova.AccelListener"/>
<plugin name="Compass" value="org.apache.cordova.CompassListener"/>
<plugin name="Media" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler"/>
<plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>
<plugin name="Contacts" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager"/>
<plugin name="File" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils"/>
<plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
<plugin name="Notification" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
<plugin name="Storage" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>
<plugin name="FileTransfer" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer"/>
<plugin name="Capture" value="org.apache.cordova.Capture"/>
<plugin name="Battery" value="org.apache.cordova.BatteryListener"/>
<plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
<plugin name="Echo" value="org.apache.cordova.Echo" />
<plugin name="Globalization" value="org.apache.cordova.Globalization"/>
<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"/>
<plugin name="VideoPlayer" value="com.phonegap.plugins.video.VideoPlayer"/>
<plugin name="PdfViewer" value="com.phonegap.plugins.pdf.PdfViewer"/>
<plugin name="FileOpener" value="com.phonegap.plugins.fileOpener.FileOpener"/>  
<plugin name="Downloader" value="com.phonegap.plugins.downloader.Downloader"/>
<plugin name="StatusBarNotification"       value="com.phonegap.plugins.statusBarNotification.StatusBarNotification"/>
</plugins>
</cordova>
```

And my index.html file is like that:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]--><head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<!-- Set the viewport width to device width for mobile -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Sid Agency App</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/file.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/downloader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/organictabs.jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#main_container").organicTabs();
    }); 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var value = window.localStorage.getItem("key");
    if (value == "5") {
        top.location.href = "dashboard.html";
    } else {
        $("#content").css("top", $("#header").height() + "px");
        $("#content").height($(window).height() - $("#footer").height() + "px");
        $("#content_inner").height($("#content").height() - $("#footer").height() + "px");

        var user_data = {
            login_id: 1234,
            pin_code: 1234
        };
       ...........//so on
```

And my App id in build.phonegap.com is 401033.

I have made some code in my src file for plugin in eclipse.

But **My issue is**

Now when I am testing the application from eclipse to my device it is working as expected.

When I am testing the app in iPhone simulator through xcode nothing is coming except some alert like gap:["Device","getDeviceInfo","Device984611098"],
 gap:["NetworkStatus","getConnectionInfo","NetworkStatus984611099"],  gap:["App","show","App984611100"] .

Now if i remove this line from both html file App is working fine in simulator.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
```

But when I am downloading the apk file from build.phonegap.com I can see everything is running fine except the plugins like **Fileopener, Downloader** (you can see i have mentioned it in config.xml file within plugin tag). None of these plugins are working at all.

Same when I am downloading .ipa file from build.phonegap.com in iPhone nothing is coming as every content is coming trough ajax i cant see them any of them but it is coming in android.

I have tried a lot to fix the problem but nothing helps. Can anyone help me? what's wrong I am doing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you installed phonegap for android for your app,
install phonegap for ios using [their guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html#iOS%20Platform%20Guide), then copy the **js/cordova.js** file from the HelloWorld app you created and use it.